# Soap not getting sent correctly, need to get the request

Tags: php, soap

I have this class to send a SOAP-request (the class also defines the header)

```
class Personinfo
{
    function __construct() {
        $this->soap = new SoapClient('mysource.wsdl',array('trace' => 1));
    }

    private function build_auth_header() {
        $auth->BrukerID = 'userid';
        $auth->Passord = 'pass';
        $auth->SluttBruker = 'name';
        $auth->Versjon = 'v1-1-0';

        $authvalues = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
        $header =  new SoapHeader('http://www.example.com', "BrukerAutorisasjon", // Rename this to the tag you need
        $authvalues, false);

        $this->soap->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
    }

    public function hentPersoninfo($params){

        $this->build_auth_header();
        $res = $this->soap->hentPersoninfo($params);
        return $res;
    }
}
```

The problem is that there's something wrong with my function and the response is an error. I'd like to find out what content I am sending with my request, but I can't figure out how.

I've tried a try/catch-block in the hentPersoninfo-function that calls `$this->soap->__getLastRequest` but it is always empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error?  Where does the error come from?  If it's from the server you're sending too, parse the error response.  If you want to know what you're sending, try wireshark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I ever start accessing a service programmatically, I use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to ensure that I know what needs sent to the service, and what I should expect back.

This way, you can ensure the issue isn't in the web service and/or in your understanding of how you should access the web service.

After you understand this, you can narrow your focus onto making the relevant SOAP framework do what you need it to do.

Comment: SoapUI OR TCPMon (http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/) can help. The second one incercepts traffic and acts like a proxy, so it shows requests and their responses

Comment: Forgot to accept this answer, so I am a bit late, but SoapUI is brilliant. I suggest it to everyone messing around with Soap-requests.